# Hide and replace UITabBar with a view, in swift

Tags: swift, replace, uitabbarcontroller, hide, uitabbar

I am still trying to hide and replace the UITabbar with a view.
In my previous question I tried in another way. It worked, but the background view is black. And I wanted something like the output I receive from below code.

Now I am trying it this way:
Code with controller name is stated below

ProjectGridViewController:

```
    @objc func eyeBtnPressed() {
        let popUpVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopViewController") as! PopViewController
        self.addChild(popUpVC)
        popUpVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(popUpVC.view)
        popUpVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
```

PopViewController:

```
class PopViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var popView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        popView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
        moveIn()
    }
    
    func moveIn() {

        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.35, y: 1.35)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
          self.view.alpha = 1.0
          UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.24) {
              self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
              self.view.alpha = 1.0
         }
      }
}
```

The output received with this code is - [Output view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4co5.png)
I just want that orange view to replace the hidden tab bar. I don't want that black bar under the view
Need help.

Comment: Resolved the issue: Got the view as I was expecting. Code -  ProjectGridViewController: `@objc func eyeBtnPressed() {
        let popUpVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopViewController") as! PopViewController
        popUpVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.custom
        self.navigationController?.present(popUpVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }`

Comment: PopViewController: `class PopViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var popView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        popView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        moveIn()
    }
    func moveIn() {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.35, y: 1.35)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
    }
}`

Comment: Didn't replace it but added a pop over